# Hide .php extension from specific files using .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I would like to permanently redirect these urls **only**:

```
http://www.example.com/privacy.php
http://www.example.com/terms.php
http://www.example.com/contacts.php
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/privacy
http://www.example.com/terms
http://www.example.com/contacts
```

Continuing to serve the contents inside corresponding `.php` files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

P.S. I edited my question because it has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question; the answer of the suggested question doesn't solve my problem

This is .htaccess current content:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteBase /   

# Adds the www. before any URL   
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]   
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]   

# Redirects index.php page to the homepage   
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R=301,L]   

# Redirects all old pages example.com/?d=124575 to http://www.example.com   
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?(.*)\ HTTP   
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Thank you for your time, but the answer in the suggested question doesn't solve my request

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
RewriteRule ^(privacy|terms|contacts)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work, 404 error

Comment: Where are you putting the rules and what are you visiting?

Comment: I put the rules at the end of my .htaccess, this is the content:<br/>  

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /

# Adds the www. before any URL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirects index.php page to the homepage
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R=301,L]

# Redirects all old pages example.com/?d=124575 to http://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]

Comment: And what happens when you add the rule I provided to the end of that, and then visit `/privacy`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use on my website.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

And it works without a failure.

Comment: Do you have the `RewriteEngine on` before the rule? If not please add it. I assumed you already have.

Comment: Yes I have it; please, see the current .htaccess I use (without problem) below my question

Comment: @Benedictus, did you manage to resolve this? If not, please post your new .htaccess with my change so that I can help you with it.